# Timer Vs Event: which one is preferable for Asynchronous processing?

Tags: c++

Ours is a huge project. I need to call certain functions in my code asynchronously to avoid some circular function calls. Upon receiving a specific input, I can call my function asynchronously either by using Event or Timer.

Which way is preferable considering Performance ?

Sending events to Event manager and handling them with an Event handler ? Or

Starting a timer and provide timeout handler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pure performance, event-driven model will be better.  Use timers only if you cannot rely on one or more of your events to get set in a timely way by the worker code, and so need a backup means by which to continue processing. This may be the case if your worker code makes external calls to a database or other remote service whose reliability or performance is unproven.